# Using a HTML attribute to load JSON through directive

Tags: angularjs, json

### The Directive

```
function CreateTable($http) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: function (element, attr) {
                return 'Hexdra/partials/' + attr.tableName + '-table.html';
            },
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                $http.get('Hexdra/app/app_data/' + iAttrs.tableData + '.json')
                     .success(function (data) {
                         var vm = scope;
                         vm.table = data;
                     });
                return vm.table;
            }
        };
    };
```

### The Html

```
<site-table table-name="goals" table-data="goals"class="span6"></site-table>
```

The directive creates a table whos template changes based on what the attribute `table-name=` defined in the Html.
What I am now having trouble with is where to define a function in the directive that uses the `$http` service to get a JSON file. Which JSON file is selected dipends on the attribute `table-data=` in the Html.

### An example of what the directive should do

Take this html -> `<site-table table-name="goals" table-data="goals"></site-table>`

And then create a table based off a template located at `partials/goals.html` and load a JSON file from `app_data/goals.json`.

Should i create a controller that is assigned to this particular directive?

Please point me in the right direction and let me try to figure it out again, instead of giving me the answer, I will learn more about directives and angular that way.

Thank you :)

### *EDIT* ->

### The Solution

With extensive help from the community the issue was solved and here is the general guide if you need to solve the same issue.

### The Html

```
<site-table table-name="goals" table-data="goals"class="span6"></site-table>
```

### The New Angular.js

### Setup

```
angular
    .module('table', [])
    .controller('TableController', TableController)
    .directive('siteTable', CreateTable)
    .factory('dataGet', JSONGet)

TableController.$inject = ['dataGet'];
JSONGet.$inject = ['$http'];
```

### The Service

```
function JSONGet($http) {
    return {
       getJSON: function (fileName) {
         return $http.get(fileName +'json').then(function (result) {
                return result.data;
            });
       }
    };
}
```

**Note**
There are several ways to define a service, this service was defined using a factory.

### The Controller

```
function TableController(dataGet) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.table = [];
    this.getJSON = function (fileName) {
        dataGet.getJSON(fileName).then(function (data) {
            vm.table = data;
        });
    }
}
```

### The Directive

```
function CreateTable() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: function (element, attr) {
            return 'Hexdra/partials/' + attr.tableName + '-table.html';
        },
        controller: 'TableController',
        controllerAs: 'TblCtrl',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
            controller.getJSON(attr.tableData);
        }
    };
 }
```

### Breaking down the directive

We have a directive that:

Is restricted to an Element, restrict: "E".

Has its own Scope, scope: true.

Has a templateUrl that will be populated with data from our AJAX call. Theres a special part to this TemplateUrl though. We could just have it set to a static unchanging address, `partials/myTemplate.html`. Instead we pass it a function that has two arguements, element and attribute (attr), this allows us to pull from elements or attributes that are assigned to this directive in the HTML. Its going to return a concatenated address, `attr.tableName` was an attribute we gave to our table directive and in our HTML we have `tableName=goals`. What ends up getting set as our templateURL is `Hexdra/partials/goals-table.html`

We give our directive a controller that has already been defined in the app. 
`controller: TableController`.

We assign that controller a new name.
`controllerAs: TblCtrl`.

We now use link and pass it a function that contains the scope, elements, attributes, and the controller that is contained within the directive. 
This allows us to call the service JSONGet that is within the controller TableController. 
So `controller.getJSON(attr.tableData)` means, find the controller (which is defined as TableController in this directive) find the function `.getJSON` and pass it what the attribute tableData is defined as in the HTML.

### Now we go to the controller

That method `.getJSON` is here and is actually a function that passes in one arguement fileName which from our directive is `attr.tableData`. The method is actually part of the `dataGet` service which takes that passed on `fileName` parameter passes it to a getJSON function which then uses the built in `$http` service from angular to make an AJAX call to get the required data to populate the table.

### The End Result.

We produce a table that has loaded its own template from whatever table-name is equal to. We also are able to populate the table with a JSON file that pulls its location from a service that uses the table-data attribute dynamically.

You can [view the plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DZR4WH01ms73hWe5sNtx?p=preview), courtesy of Mr. Juarez

Comment: what you wan to do with your data.? your question is not clear, if you give more information, i can help you.

Comment: I have edited the question to better explain. Just how you helped me with defining an attribute so that the template would change based off of an Html attribute, I now need help with using an html attribute in my directive that will effect which JSON data is used to populate the table. I would like a pointer in the right direction rather than a straight answer unless I still cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **create a Controller** which will manipulate all the data that you are going to show in your view, in your **directive you should only have DOM manipulations**.

After creating the Controller you should **create a service** which will have a function that does the $http call.

In the controller you should have an attribute which will be referenced from the html of the directive that will be the data that you are going to display, if that is what you want.

Comment: You can create a controller in a directive, when should one do so?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question. If you are referring when to create a Controller for a directive, you create it when you have to manipulate data that is going to be shown to the user or when you have to get data from other services.

Comment: I was wondering about the difference of defining a controller in the directive with the object notation, or defining it outside the directive and the directive is placed inside the controller in the html.

Comment: For a better legibility you should have the controller in a different file or section of your file, and only reference it in your directive by the name. The directive has an attribute called controller in which you can assign an already existing controller or a new instance for the directive. You are just going to have a CreateTableController with the call to the service and data manipulation and a service RetrieveJSONService with the $http call

Comment: I created a service, and it does a `$http.get` but the url is static and Im stuck on how to get the HTML attribute `table-data` into the service so that it is dynamic. For the templateUrl of the directive, I was able to use a function that contained the elements and attributes of the html, is there an equivalent for services?

Comment: Call the controller from the directive with something like:
myController.getTableData(iAttrs.tableData);
And in the controller you just call the service with the parameter that you received from the directive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110068/discussion-between-rodrigo-juarez-and-drew-ackerman).